# How can I deploy a zend framework 2 php app to CloudControl?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, cloudcontrol

I have the zend skeleton app, the framework is detected but I still run into trouble:
Constructor Zend\Stdlib\Glob::glob() cannot be static 
Now Im not sure is that related to the php version of cloud control, or other configurations I should take into account.

For example, database logging instead of file logging and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting a basic Zend 2 app running, check out the [cloudControl Zend2 guide](https://github.com/cloudControl/documentation/blob/master/Guides/PHP/Zend%202.md).

Comment: The old guide at https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Guides/PHP/Zend%20Framework%201.11 is slightly outdated and will be replaced in the following days.

Comment: To get a newer PHP version, simply use append --stack pinky to the deploy command. Other than that, you want to make sure your logging goes to syslog and you store sessions in a database or in memcache etc. to be able scale out later. The Zend 2 Framework guide Stefan mentioned is currently still work in progress. But it's a good start.